# Is there a counterpart/antidote for \obeylines?

Tags: plain-tex, catcodes

The `\obeylines` command tells TeX to preserve line endings, which is useful for poetry and various other things. I can limit the effect of `\obeylines` by wrapping it in a scope, like so:

```
{\obeylines
    We obey, and end up on separate lines.
    We obey.
}
We disobey, and end up on the same line.
We disobey.
```

This is practically always the way to go, or newlines breaking up formatting code will break up more than that. But, out of curiosity: is there also a command that resets TeX's handling of line endings? Googling for `\disobeylines` turned up some roll-your-own implementations, but I'm curious whether Donald Knuth wrote an antidote into Plain TeX itself, too.

Comment: No, there's no "official" one. Knuth recommends to use it in a group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The definition of `\obeylines` is

```
% In \obeylines, we say `\let^^M=\par' instead of `\def^^M{\par}'
% since this allows, for example, `\let\par=\cr \obeylines \halign{...'
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
  \gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\par}%
  \global\let^^M\par} % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
```

So you can try:

```
\def\disobeylines{\catcode`\^^M=5 }
```

The example:

```
\def\disobeylines{\catcode`\^^M=5 }

\obeylines
    We obey, and end up on separate lines.
    We obey.
\disobeylines
We disobey, and end up on the same line.
We disobey.

\bye
```

---

**EDIT**

As egreg pointed out in his comment, Donald Knuth doesn't provide any `\disobeylines`. In the TeXBook at page 94 the command `\obeylines` is introduced with the following paragraph:

> You may have several consecutive lines of input for which you want the
> output to appear line-for-line in the same way. One solution is to
> type `\par` at the end of each input line; but that’s somewhat of a
> nuisance, so plain TeX provides the abbreviation `\obeylines`, which
> causes each end-of-line in the input to be like `\par`. After you say
> `\obeylines` you will get one line of output per line of input, unless
> an input line ends with `%` or unless it is so long that it must be
> broken. For example, you probably want to use `\obeylines` if you are
> typesetting a poem. **Be sure to enclose `\obeylines` in a group,
> unless you want this "poetry mode" to continue to the end of your
> document.**

Comment: or better `\def\disobeylines{\catcode ‘\^^M=5 }`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Do you mean the space?

Comment: yes otherwise `\disobeylines 1 is a good number...` doesn't do what you want

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed -- every time I forget this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I run the code ```\def\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let ^^M\par }``` in my preamble (as a test), I get “File ended while scanning definition of `\obeylines`.” It seems to be the `\let ^^M\par` part that causes the issue.

Comment: @Gaussler I wrote the truth, but not the whole truth, added more of the plain tex context for the definition.