# Why is this code not working?

Tags: compiling, tex-core, catcodes

On this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57318/is-there-a-counterpart-antidote-for-obeylines), one answer states that `\obeylines` is defined as

```
\def\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let ^^M\par }
```

However TeX complains when I try to compile the following code

```
\def\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let ^^M\par }
\def\disobeylines{\catcode`\^^M=5 }

\obeylines
    We obey, and end up on separate lines.
    We obey.
\disobeylines
We disobey, and end up on the same line.
We disobey.

\bye
```

The situation doesn't get any better when I change the first line to

```
\def\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M=13 \let^^M=\par }
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: This question could probably do with a better title.

Comment: You don't need to define `\obeylines`, do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX performs a `\def`, it just stores tokens with their current category code. In your case you are storing

> `\catcode` • `` ` ``<sub>12</sub> • `\^^M` • `\active` • `\let` `^^M`<sub>5</sub> • `\par`

(bullets separate tokens). So when your `\obeylines` macro is called, `^^M` becomes active, but `\let^^M` will throw an error of “Missing control sequence”.

Actually, this analysis is not the full truth, because the `^^M` with category code 5 in the body of the definition will cause the line to be finished and `\par}` ignored. So the error you get is different. Doing similar things with other characters would have the same problem described above.

If you look in `plain.tex` you see

```
% In \obeylines, we say `\let^^M=\par' instead of `\def^^M{\par}'
% since this allows, for example, `\let\par=\cr \obeylines \halign{...'
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
  \gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\par}%
  \global\let^^M\par} % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
```

so what's actually stored is

> `\catcode` • `` ` ``<sub>12</sub> • `\^^M` • `\active` • `\let` `^^M`<sub>13</sub> • `\par`

which does the job. The `\global\let^^M\par` can be without the `\global`, but you could incur into problems if page breaks come along.

Comment: Thanks to you: now I know of the existence of `plain.tex`. Very good answer.

Comment: @egreg ``The \global\let^^M\par can be without the \global, but you could incur into problems if page breaks come along.`` You must have been thinking about something related (contents of `\obeylines` will be interrupted by a page break?) but distinct, because the `\global` in your quote of `plain.tex` is simply there to give some definition to the active `^^M`, and it wouldn't have any effet without `\global`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `^^M` to be active at time of definition, in order for the `\let^^M\par` to be legal. Check plain.tex for one way.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I don't understand: isn't \catcode`\^^M=13 making it active?

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia No, it only does when `\obeylines` is called; but you need `^^M` to be active in order to do `\let^^M=\par` and it isn't if the definition is not made when `^^M` is active.

Comment: @egreg Now I see. I did this: `\catcode\`\^^M=13\def\obeylines{\catcode\`\^^M=13 \let ^^M=\par }\catcode\`\^^M=5` and it worked!